# UWP Binding. Something is not right

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I'm new to C# and UWP. After many days of reading official microsoft docks and stackoverflow I still cannot understand what am I doing wrong.

Here is extremely simple test app.

I am trying to change grid's background on click. When application starts the grid's background is **bg-1.jpg** as expected. After click the value of property **PicturePath** have changed, but Grid's background have not.
What am I missing?

**Here is a simple xaml page**

```
 <Page
    x:Class="Test.Views.StartPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid PointerPressed="Grid_PointerPressed">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding PicturePath, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
  </Page>
```

**Code behind**

```
public sealed partial class StartPage : Page
    {
        public StartPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new {
                TestBackgroundClass.getInstance().PicturePath,
            };
        }

        private void Grid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestBackgroundClass.getInstance().PicturePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/bg-2.jpg";
        }
    }
```

**and a singleton class**

```
public class TestBackgroundClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static TestBackgroundClass instance;

        private string _picturePath { get; set; }

        public string PicturePath
            {
             get
               {
                return _picturePath;
               }
             set
               { 
                _picturePath = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
             }

        public TestBackgroundClass()
        {
            _picturePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/bg-1.jpg"
        }

        public static TestBackgroundClass getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null) instance = new TestBackgroundClass();
            return instance;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting `DataContext = TestBackgroundClass.getInstance();`

Comment: Yes this is working, thank you. Is there a way to have multiple objects in DataContext and still have data binding?

Comment: It won't work in that way. You need to have a `ViewModel` (similar to `Controller` in MVC pattern). That will hold the `Properties` and those will be binded in your `View`. You can have different `DataContext` for different `Controls` if needed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation.

Comment: Your life will be easier if you use x:Bind and keep the properties in the Page. If you make a habit of using that approach it saves you from always having to fuss with the DataContext.